# method "onClick" in butterknife is not work?

Tags: java, android, butterknife

This is the MainActicity:

```
package com.example.a10648.demo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.OnClick;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@BindView(R.id.button)
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
}

@OnClick(R.id.button)
public void onClick() {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"ok",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

This is the xml  file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.a10648.demo.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button!" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and I have 
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'
this is build.gradle in app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.a10648.demo"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'
 }
```

the method onClick in bufferknife is not work,
when I clicked the button ,there is no Toast to appear?
I don't know why happen like this ?

Comment: is there any error comming ?

Comment: @VishweshJainkuniya that's useless. This question is about butterknife

Answer (score 7):

fistly,make sure your project level build.gradle as follows:

```
   buildscript {  
    repositories {  
        jcenter()  
    }  
    dependencies {  
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'  
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'  
    }  
}
```

Pay special attention to this line of code. 
Don't ignore!!!

```
 classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
```

Then ,look at your app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.a10648.demo"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'
apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'
}
```

Pay special attention to three lines of code. 
Don't ignore!!!

```
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'
apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'
```

Then ,everything is ok! I am so happy!
Thank you to  一叶飘舟
This is his personal page in CSDN .

http://blog.csdn.net/jdsjlzx/article/details/51354433

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you should include ButterKnife compiler as well:

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1' 
apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

if you read the readme, you can see ->

Configure your project-level build.gradle to include the 'android-apt' plugin:

```
classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
```

so build.gradle:

```
 buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
            classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

Then, apply the 'android-apt' plugin in your module-level build.gradle and add the Butter Knife dependencies:

```
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

android {
  ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
  apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
}
```

So your build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.a10648.demo"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
}
```